# Using two languages for natbib cite commands

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I write my thesis in English, but need to include a summary in Swedish, which I want to include in my latex document. Therefore I need to switch between the two languages when I use the `\citep` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
This is the first referece \citep{baker_two_2010}.

Here I want to change language from English \{and\} to Swedish \{och\}.

This is the second reference \citep{barss_phases_2006}

\bibliography{bibex}
\bibliographystyle{linquiry2}

\end{document}
```

The first `\citep` command will print (Baker and Vinokurova 2010). The second `\citep` command will print (Barss and Carnie 2006). I want the second one to print (Barss och Carnie 2006). I do note want the final bibliography to mix languages. All entries in the bibliography shall be in English, not Swedish, which is the current output.

These are the entries in the `.bib` file.

```
@article{baker_two_2010,
    title = {Two modalities of case assignment: Case in {Sakha}},
    volume = {28},
    issn = {0167-806X},
    doi = {10.1007/s11049-010-9105-1},
    language = {English},
    number = {3},
    journal = {Natural Language \& Linguistic Theory},
    author = {Baker, Mark C. and Vinokurova, Nadya},
    year = {2010},
    keywords = {Agreement, Case assignment, Dependent case, Sakha, Turkic languages},
    pages = {593--642},
}

@article{barss_phases_2006,
  title={Phases and nominal interpretation},
  author={Carnie, Andrew and Barss, Andrew},
  year= {2006},
journal = {Research in Language},
   volume = {4},
   pages = {127-132}
}
```

[This](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/advice/latex/linquiry2.bst) is the link to the `.bst` file used in the MWE.

Comment: This is not easy to do, since the `linquiry2.bst` file is not set up for mulilanguage support (which is hard to do with natbib anyway.) I would suggest switching to `biblatex`, which has straightforward language support. But since this is only a small part of the document, it might be easier just to insert the citations as regular text at the end.

Comment: I suspected that that was the case, but I thought I should ask if there is a straightforward way to actually achieve that the "real" way, by tweaking a package. I will furthermore look into the `biblatex` option.

Comment: Could you just write out "(Barss och Carnie 2006)" by hand in the Swedish language section of the document? The readers probably won't notice the difference. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is straightforward to do with Biblatex. (Too late for original question now, but may be of interest to others seeing the question.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[swedish, british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibex.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is some text \citep{baker_two_2010}.

\begin{otherlanguage}{swedish}
Svensk sammanfattning: Läs \citet{barss_phases_2006}!
\end{otherlanguage}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Results in
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the [natlib citation style](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Natbib_citation_styles), I have a `bibstyle.bst` file with the following section, where you could change the language of specific words in the citation:

```
%% Here are the language-specific definitions for explicit words.
%% Each function has a name bbl.xxx where xxx is the English word.
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "och"}
```

In the `main.tex`,

```
\bibliographystyle{bibstyle.bst}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

Hope this helps.